# kubernetes metrics server don't start

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I try to connect in the dashboard of kubernetes.

I have the latest version of kubernetes v1.12 with kubeadm , in a server.

I download from github the metrics-server and run:

> Kubctl create -f deploy/1.8+

but i get this error

> kube-system   metrics-server-5cbbc84f8c-tjfxd   0/1    Pending 0 12m

with out log to debug

> error: the server doesn't have a resource type "logs"

I don't want to install heapster because is DEPRECATED.

**UPDATE**

Hello, and thanks.

i run the taint command i get:

> error: at least one taint update is required

and the command

> kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -n kube-system

i get this output:

```
Name:                   metrics-server
Namespace:              kube-system
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 18 Oct 2018 14:34:42 +0000
Labels:                 k8s-app=metrics-server
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
 kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:     {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":    {"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"metrics-server"},"name":"metrics-...
 Selector:               k8s-app=metrics-server
 Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1      unavailable
 StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
 MinReadySeconds:        0
 RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
 Pod Template:
   Labels:           k8s-app=metrics-server
   Service Account:  metrics-server
   Containers:
    metrics-server:
Image:        k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
Port:         <none>
Host Port:    <none>
Environment:  <none>
Mounts:
  /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
Volumes:
tmp-dir:
Type:    EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
Medium:  
 Conditions:
   Type           Status  Reason
   ----           ------  ------
   Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
 OldReplicaSets:  <none>
 NewReplicaSet:   metrics-server-5cbbc84f8c (1/1 replicas created)
 Events:          <none>
```

Command:

> kubectl get nodes

The output for this is just the IP of the node, and nothing special.

Any ideas, or what to do to work the dashboard for kubernetes.

Comment: provide output of `kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -n kube-system`

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are trying setup metrics-server on your master node.

If you issue  `kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -n kube-system` I believe you will see something like this:

> Name:                   metrics-server Namespace:
>   kube-system CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 18 Oct 2018 15:57:34 +0000
>   Labels:                 k8s-app=metrics-server Annotations:
>   deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1 Selector:
>   k8s-app=metrics-server Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated |
>   1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable

But if you will describe your node you will see taint that prevent you from scheduling new pods on master node:

```
kubectl get nodes

NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kube-master-1   Ready    master   17m   v1.12.1

kubectl describe node kube-master-1

Name:               kube-master-1
...
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

You have to remove this taint:

```
kubectl taint node kube-master-1 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
node/kube-master-1 untainted
```

Result:

```
 kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-node-xvc77                       2/2     Running   0          20m
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-rj4wh                1/1     Running   0          21m
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-vsjsf                1/1     Running   0          21m
kube-system   etcd-kube-master-1                      1/1     Running   0          20m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kube-master-1            1/1     Running   0          20m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kube-master-1   1/1     Running   0          20m
kube-system   kube-proxy-xp5zh                        1/1     Running   0          21m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kube-master-1            1/1     Running   0          20m
kube-system   metrics-server-5cbbc84f8c-l2t76         1/1     Running   0          18m
```

But this is not the best approach. Good approach is to join worker and set up metrics-server there. There won't be any issues and there is no need to touch taint on master node.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply,

I update the question.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer by "Vit" is correct, either remove taint from existing node group or create new node group without any taint.